# Oracle PLSQL Long run issue with dynamic query

Tags: oracle, plsql

`The below code have long run issue. The code will prepare dynamic update query and doing update statement with logs. please help to optimize this query. thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
DECLARE
TYPE MFU_REC_TYPE
IS
  RECORD
  (
    Product_Category VARCHAR2(4000),
    SOURCE_COLUMN    VARCHAR2(4000),
    SOURCE_VALUE     VARCHAR2(4000),
    TARGET_COLUMNS   VARCHAR2(4000),
    TARGET_VALUE     VARCHAR2(4000),
    TP_SYS_NM        VARCHAR2(4000) );
TYPE MFU_table_type
IS
  TABLE OF MFU_REC_TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  MFU_VALUES MFU_table_type;
TYPE log_REC_TYPE
IS
  RECORD
  (
    log_type        VARCHAR2(4000),
    Update_query    VARCHAR2(4000),
    Process_Message VARCHAR2(4000) );
TYPE log_table_type
IS
  TABLE OF log_REC_TYPE;
  Log_VALUES log_table_type:=log_table_type();
  LS_SQL          VARCHAR2(1000);
  LS_MFU_TABLE    VARCHAR2(1000);
  LS_AGG_TABLE    VARCHAR2(1000);
  ls_update_query VARCHAR2(4000);
  lb_exception    BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  lb_exception :=false;
  LS_MFU_TABLE := @MFU_Table_name ;
  LS_AGG_TABLE :=@AGG_Table_name;
  
  LS_SQL       := 'SELECT Product_Category,
SOURCE_COLUMN,    
SOURCE_VALUE,    
TARGET_COLUMNS,  
TARGET_VALUE, 
TP_SYS_NM   
FROM '||LS_MFU_TABLE;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ls_sql BULK COLLECT INTO MFU_values;
  
  FOR i IN 1 .. MFU_values.COUNT
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      Log_VALUES.extend;
      
      ls_update_query           := 'update  '||LS_AGG_TABLE||'  set  ' ||MFU_values(i).TARGET_COLUMNS|| ' = '||''''||MFU_values(i).TARGET_VALUE||''''|| ' where trim(' ||MFU_values(i).SOURCE_COLUMN||') = trim( '||''''|| MFU_values(i).SOURCE_VALUE||''''|| ') and  trim(PRODUCT_CATEGORY) = trim('||''''|| MFU_values(i).Product_Category||''''|| ') ' ;
      
      Log_VALUES(i).Update_query:=ls_update_query;
      
      EXECUTE immediate ls_update_query;
      
      Log_VALUES(i).Process_Message:=SQL%ROWCOUNT||' rows got updated.';
      Log_VALUES(i).log_type       :='OK';
      
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      Log_VALUES(i).Process_Message:=SQLERRM;
      Log_VALUES(i).log_type       :='ERROR';
      lb_exception                 :=true;
    END;
    
  END LOOP;
  
  IF lb_exception THEN
    ROLLBACK;
  END IF;
  
  FOR i IN Log_VALUES.FIRST..Log_VALUES.LAST
  LOOP
    INSERT
    INTO @table_name
      (
        log_type,
        Update_query,
        Process_Message
      )
      VALUES
      (
        Log_VALUES(i).log_type,
        Log_VALUES(i).Update_query,
        Log_VALUES(i).Process_Message
      );
  END LOOP;
  
  COMMIT;
 
END;
```

`

The above code have long run issue. The code will prepare dynamic update query and doing update statement with logs. please help to optimize this query. thanks in advance.

Comment: You are performing row-by-row update that is slow by design. Use `merge` statement instead.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; an explanation (in English, not code) of the logic you want to implement; and the expected output for your sample data. There may be ways to rewrite your query using dynamic SQL to generate a `MERGE` statement (as mentioned by @astentx) but it depends on your logic (as there are cases when it may be impossible to map your dynamic logic to a single statement).

Comment: Why do you use `WHERE trim(...) = trim(...)`? Is the quality of your data that poor? Better trim the values when you insert it.

Comment: @astentx how can you use `MERGE` when columns names and conditions are not known at design time?

Comment: In the same way as you build dynamic update, @WernfriedDomscheit. Similar columns may be grouped together and values may be calculated via `case` expression.

Comment: @astentx It is a simple update, how can you use it together with the select? Be aware, the select returns not just the values, it also returns the columns to be updated and WHERE conditions. Of course, you can use `MERGE` but it would be still one command for each record, thus performance will remain poor.

Comment: On which columns did you create indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Better use this:

```
ls_update_query := 
    'update '||LS_AGG_TABLE||' set ' || MFU_values(i).TARGET_COLUMNS|| ' = :TARGET_COLUMNS '||
     ' where trim(' ||MFU_values(i).SOURCE_COLUMN||') = :SOURCE_COLUMN '||
     ' and trim(PRODUCT_CATEGORY) = :PRODUCT_CATEGORY' ;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ls_update_query USING MFU_values(i).TARGET_VALUE, TRIM(MFU_values(i).SOURCE_VALUE), TRIM(MFU_values(i).Product_Category);
```

For the insert, have a look at [FORALL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/FORALL-statement.html#GUID-C45B8241-F9DF-4C93-8577-C840A25963DB) statement.